# How to label only last point in DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, labeling, date-and-time

Working on a `DateListPlot` in Mathematica 12.1, and I only want to label the *last* point in the resulting chart with the second value (the number of COVID-19 cases). How?

Here's the code I have thus far (minus the first line, which is a `CloudConnect` command to get the data.) The `ResourceObject` call in the first line below is an effort to force it to get the latest data.

```
resource = ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"];
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"][Select[MatchQ[Entity["Country","UnitedStates"],#Country]&&!MissingQ[#AdministrativeDivision]&]][GroupBy["Country"]][ All, Total, #ConfirmedCases &];
diffs = Differences[data[Entity["Country","UnitedStates"]]];
Export["/home/pi/Pictures/COVIDCharts.png",Row[{DateListPlot[data,PlotLabel->"Total COVID-19 Cases, U.S.", PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->"Detailed",ImageSize->Large,LabelingFunction->(# &)],
DateListPlot[diffs,PlotLabel->"Daily New Cases Reported, U.S.", PlotRange->All,PlotTheme->"Detailed",ImageSize->Large,LabelingFunction->(# &)]}]]
```

[image: Image of the first chart]

Comment: Update to my own posting: I figured out using `#[[2]]` gives me just the second value (with a decimal point at the end); just now need to know how to only show the latest (last) value.

Comment: Quite related ?https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/219501/1089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Row[{DateListPlot[data, 
   PlotLabels -> {Column @ {DateString @ First[Normal[Values[data]]] @ "LastTime", 
       First[Normal[Values[data]]] @ "LastValue"}}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Total COVID-19 Cases, U.S.", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 550], 
  DateListPlot[diffs, 
   PlotLabels -> {Column @ {DateString @ diffs @ "LastTime", diffs @ "LastValue"}}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Daily New Cases Reported, U.S.", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 550]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Or

```
label1 = Placed[Column@
  {DateString[#, {"MonthName", " ", "Day", ", ", "Year"}], #2} & @@ 
    (First[Normal[Values[data]]] /@ {"LastTime", "LastValue"}), After];

label2 = Placed[Column@
  {DateString[#, {"MonthName", " ", "Day", ", ",  "Year"}], #2} & @@ 
    (diffs /@ {"LastTime", "LastValue"}),  After];

Row[{DateListPlot[data, PlotLabels -> label1, 
   PlotLabel -> "Total COVID-19 Cases, U.S.", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 550], 
  DateListPlot[diffs, PlotLabels -> label2, 
   PlotLabel -> "Daily New Cases Reported, U.S.", PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 550]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for; but I need the layout of the first solution with the label format (date only) of the second; I'll keep pluggin'. :-)

Comment: Figured it out, it's admittedly a kludge: `StringReplace[DateString @ data @ "LastDate"," 12:00 am"->""]`